# Select max value from column for every value in other two columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm working on a webapp that tracks tvshows, and I need to get all episodes id's that are season finales, which means, the highest episode number from all seasons, for all tvshows.

This is a simplified version of my "episodes" table.

```
 id   tvshow_id   season   epnum
 ---|-----------|--------|-------
 1  |     1     |    1   |   1
 2  |     1     |    1   |   2
 3  |     1     |    1   |   3
 4  |     1     |    2   |   1
 5  |     1     |    2   |   2
 6  |     2     |    1   |   1
 7  |     2     |    1   |   2
 8  |     2     |    1   |   3
 9  |     2     |    1   |   4
10  |     2     |    2   |   1
11  |     2     |    2   |   2
```

The expect output:

```
 id
 ---|
 3  |
 5  |
 9  |
11  |
```

I've managed to get this working for the latest season but I can't make it work for all seasons.

I've also tried to take some ideas from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612231/how-can-i-select-rows-with-maxcolumn-value-distinct-by-another-column-in-sql) but I can't seem to find a way to add the tvshow_id in there.

I'm using Postgres v10

Comment: in which database?

Comment: It's in the end of the question: "I'm using Postgres v10"

Comment: If you say you already got parts of it working, it'd be good to see your source code. It's easier to fix a small error than writing it all anew.

Comment: I don't think it will be useful because its limited to the latest season and the tvshow_id is hardcoded, so the correct answer is unlikely to use any of this.. but here you go https://pastebin.com/DdVQMTx2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT Id from
(Select *, Row_number() over (partition by tvshow_id,season order by epnum desc) as ranking from tbl)c
Where ranking=1
```

Comment: How would this relate to @Vivek 's answer in terms of performance ? I got the same result (both output and operation time) and the test table that im using is quite small (~150 rows), so I dont have an idea.

Comment: @nip I'm not sure about PostgreS, but window functions are usually very performant in most databases I've used. Plus it keeps things set-based. Also, `WHERE x IN (1,2,3)` is pretty much `WHERE x = 1 OR x=2 OR x=3`. For large lists, that can get pretty slow.

Comment: @Shawn Well, now I'm concerced because this table is going to get somewhat big and I've added another WHERE IN to filter the tvshow_id's, since I only want the season finales from a certain number of tvshows. How would this work (the filtering) with this answer without using WHERE IN ? Is this even possible ?

Comment: @nip I'd use the `ROW_NUMBER()` method. Use Ajay Gupta's answer. http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-row_number/

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below SQL to get your result, using GROUP BY with sub-subquery as:

```
select id from tab_x
where (tvshow_id,season,epnum) in (
select tvshow_id,season,max(epnum)
from tab_x
group by tvshow_id,season)
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the simple query to get desired result. Below query is also good in performance with help of using **distinct on()** clause

```
  select
   distinct on (tvshow_id,season)
   id
  from your_table
  order by tvshow_id,season ,epnum desc
```